# Is there a pun in Matthew 9:30?

Tags: matthew, miracle, pun

After Jesus heals two blind men, he *sternly* warns them,

> 'See that no one knows about it.'

I have a feeling that the word 'see' here is a reference to their previous blindness. I find it intriguing that in the gospels, Jesus often asks people who receive miracles not to say anything about it.

Could it be that Matthew wanted to portray Jesus as somewhat tongue-in-cheek, considering that being cured of blindness is something very hard to hide?

As a teacher, this would make for a thought-provoking Bible lesson

Answer (score 3):

It is true that the frequent Greek verb ὁράω (I see) is used (as in English) in several senses:

- seeing with one's eyes
- perceiving with the mind either spiritually or physically
- warning to ensure something in done or not done, as in Matt 9:30.

The latter is why a word-for-word translation of the Greek still conveys the same meaning in English as in Greek.  This word is used regularly in this sense such as Matt 8:4, 9:30, 16:6, 19:10, 24:26, Mark 1:44, 8:15, Luke 12:15, 1 Thess 5:15, Rev 19:10, 22:9, etc.  See also Matt 27:4, Acts 18:15, Heb 8:5, etc.

In Matt 9:30 ὁράω is in the imperative mood, ie, a command by Jesus which, according to V31, they immediately disobeyed.

Now, whether one calls the use of ὁράω in Matt 9:30 a pun is a matter of taste.  There is a more pointed example of this in John 9 where Jesus deliberately contrasts the sight of a newly seeing man with the spiritual blindness of the pharisees in the final verses of the chapter - but that is another question.